# fill options of pack Manager not being recognized

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After switching from "from tkinter import *" to "import tkinter as tk" I started getting the following error from the pack managers "fill" option:
"NameError: name 'BOTH' is not defined"

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.test = tk.Label(self, text="Hi")
        self.test.pack(fill=BOTH)

Gui().mainloop()
```

Anyone has an idea why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `tk.BOTH` or as string, i.e. `fill="both"`.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, thank you very much.